# A list of structure with Python

Tags: python

I am new in python,
I want work with structured lists:

```
class X_ItemSet:                # Structure of an Item
    Item = []
    ItemTID = []

oneItem = X_ItemSet             #one instance of X_ItemSet
ListTID = [X_ItemSet]           #Liste of X_ItemSet

oneItem.Item.append(1)
oneItem.ItemTID.append("a")

ListTID.append(oneItem)
del oneItem[:]
```

my problem is when deleting oneItem also ListTID will be empty
what should i do to keep values in ListTID when deleting oneItem?

Comment: Python passes things by reference, so when you delete oneItem, it disappears from everywhere including your list. Generally, you should not be deleting variables and let GC handle things. Why do you want to explicitly delete it anyway?

Comment: I tried running your code and got `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion` on the last line. If I change it to `del oneItem`, `ListTID` still contains values. Are you sure that this exact code is causing ListTID to be empty?

Comment: You haven't created a single instance of `X_ItemSet`. Neither `oneItem = X_ItemSet` nor `ListTID = [X_ItemSet]` creates an instance. You're using the actual class object there, and `Item` and `ItemTID` are class variables instead of instance variables.

Comment: In case if you do not know, `Item` and `ItemTID` are static variables to class `X_ItemSet`

Comment: @Mad Wombat: that was a small part of my code, i want del it to fill it again (i use loop)

Comment: @Kevin: yes its wrong the correct is :    del oneItem.Item[:]